# Flagging column based on condition using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table like this ,

```
Address  X1         X2    
ABC      RF_Error   PRE
ABC      RF_Error   PRE
DEF      WIFI       PRE
DEF      WIFI       PRE
DEF      WIFI       POST
HGI      RF_Error   PRE
ABC      SYS_INFO   PRE
ABC      SYS_INFO   POST
```

I want to check for Address with respect to X1 , POST is not occurred in X2 then I want to flag with the X1 value as Yes or No.

My output should look like,

```
Address  X1         X2     RF_ERROR   WIFI   SYS_INFO
ABC      RF_Error   PRE       YES
ABC      RF_Error   PRE       YES
DEF      WIFI       PRE                NO
DEF      WIFI       PRE                NO
DEF      WIFI       POST               NO
HGI      RF_Error   PRE       YES
ABC      SYS_INFO   PRE                          NO
ABC      SYS_INFO   POST                         NO
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option would be to use aggregation to generate the flags you want, and then join back to your original table:

```
SELECT
    t1.Address,
    t1.X1,
    t1.X2,
    t2.RF_ERROR,
    t2.WIFI,
    t2.SYS_INFO
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Address,
        X1,
        IF(COUNT(CASE WHEN X2 = 'POST' THEN 1 END) = 0, 'YES', '') AS RF_ERROR,
        IF(COUNT(CASE WHEN X1 = 'WIFI' THEN 1 END) > 0, 'NO', '') AS WIFI,
        IF(COUNT(CASE WHEN X1 = 'SYS_INFO' THEN 1 END) > 0, 'NO', '') AS SYS_INFO
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Address, X1
) t2
    ON t1.Address = t2.Address AND t1.X1 = t2.X1
ORDER BY
    t1.Address;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Then maybe my answer would have to change.  But then, so would your question `:-)`

Comment: Edit your question and please show us the real problem, thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer, please delete all your comments here, they belong under your question or in the question, not here.

Comment: For the Same Address "ABC" if X1 doesn't contain RF_ERROR  then its giving Yes in RF_ERROR

Comment: I'm not changing my answer a third time.  You should open a new question at this point.

Comment: SYS_INFO Value is coming in RF_ERROR

Comment: I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Just Check the above sql fiddle link  this Ur already right in ur code !

Comment: I asked as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179153/pivot-based-on-flag-condition